# Load data into detailed view from list sencha touch 2 MVC

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm trying to use .setActiveItem to display detailed info on items in a listview (Ext.dataview.List) in a Sencha 2.1 MVC app. The problem is that I can't get the detailed view to load the data.

I've tried many different methods of getting the detailed view to show data including setData, setRecord and Update (see below for some of my latest tries).

Most of the results I keep getting when searching the forums, stackoverflow and google are for sencha apps not using the MVC model. 
(Oh, using .push this works fine but due to other reasons I'm moving away from the navigation view).

From my controller:

```
showDetail: function(list, record) {
    /*this.getMain().push({
        xtype: 'labdetail',
        title: record.fullName(),
        data: record.getData()
    });*/
//The code above works, but only as long as I stay with navigation view...
    console.log("showDetail");
       //Ext.getCmp('labdetail').update(record.data);
       //LabDetail.update(record.data);
       //Ext.fly('labdetail').setData(record.data);
       //Ext.getCmp('labdetail').setData(record.data);
       //Ext.component('Labblistan.view.LabDetail').destroy();
       //Ext.getCmp('Labblistan.view.LabDetail').destroy();
       //Ext.fly('labdetail').destroy();
       //var DetailView = Ext.create('Labblistan.view.LabDetail'); //If I create the view the console complains I need to destroy previous views with the same ID, hence the different destroy() approaches above
       //DetailView.setRecord(record);
       Ext.getCmp('mainpanel').setActiveItem('labdetail'); //This navigates to the right view, but it's empty
},
```

My detailview:

```
Ext.define('Labblistan.view.LabDetail', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'labdetail',
id: 'labdetail',
config: {
    title: '{Analysis}',
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    scrollable: 'vertical',
    fullscreen: true,
    tpl: [
        '<div style=position:absolute;top:50px;><p>Info about {Analysis}</p><p>{Comment}</p></div>'
    ],
       },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is best practice but this is how I got it working:

```
Ext.getCmp('mainpanel').setActiveItem({
       xtype: 'labdetail',
       title: 'Detaljinformation',
       data: record.getData()
});
```

Comment: This seems fine. I do it similarly: I usually provide a `record` config to my custom views, and then in `applyRecord` I do `this.setData(record.getData())`, but in the end it is the same.